# Updating table in as400 using table in excel with vba

Tags: excel, inner-join, ibm-midrange, updating, vba

I want to update table in as400 using table in excel worksheet like this :

Table1 [as400]

```
REFNO   QTY
1       10
2       12 
3       20
```

Table2 [excel worksheet]

```
REFNO   QTY
1       13
2       15 
3       22
```

Qty in Table1 updated from Table2 using VBA so the ouput will be like this :

Table1 [as400]

```
REFNO   QTY
1       13
2       15 
3       22
```

I have write codes like this :

```
Dim s1 As Worksheet
Dim BRDa As ADODB.Connection
Dim RS As ADODB.Recordset
Dim b As Integer

Set RS = New ADODB.Recordset
Set BRDa = New ADODB.Connection
BRDa.ConnectionString = "provider=ABC; Data source=XYZ; user id=OK1; password=OK2"
BRDa.Open

On Error Resume Next 
Dim QRY1, QRY2 As String
QRY1 = "SELECT * FROM TABLE1 INNER JOIN S1.TABLE2 ON TABLE1.REFNO=TABLE2.REFNO"
RS.Open QRY1, BRDa, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic

b = 0

Do While Not RS.EOF
QRY2 = "UPDATE TABLE1 SET TABLE1.QTY = TABLE2.QTY WHERE TABLE1.REFNO=TABLE2.REFNO"
BRDa.Execute QRY2, dbFailOnError

b = b + 1
RS.MoveNext
Loop
TextBox1.Text = b
RS.Close

BRDa.Close
End If
End Sub
```

But it doesn't work. Could someone help me pleasee... T__T!! Thank you..

Comment: Have you tried this http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.hardware.ibm.midrange/177020 or this http://newsolutions.de/forum-systemi-as400-i5-iseries/threads/17514-Excel-gt-VBA-gt-SQL-gt-AS400

Comment: I've tried, but seems it was different with my case. Any other suggestion please.. Tks.

Comment: Your SQL doesn't work: TABLE2  in QRY2 is not defined. Why would you need Excel and VBA for all of this, since you don't use the worksheet content?

Comment: I mean that the purpose of TABLE2 in excel worksheet is for the reference that will be use for updating TABLE1 in as400. I have average 2million rows that will be updated every month, so that I have to use vba to shorten the lead time of updating process. Yes, your correct, my sql doesn't work because it just only my trials because inner join couldn't be used for different database and I need help :)

Comment: You want to update 2 million rows using Excel? Good luck with that. I just wanted to give you some starters as I haven't done this by myself.

Comment: Ou,sorry, I was miss-type. I mean 2 thousand not 2 million :) OK Mr. Martin, thanks for your comment

Comment: I have compile my codes but it was failed and the error message : Table2 couldn't not be found in as400 database. In my opinion, since I have used inner join codes, it couldn't be placed at the same sub macro with as400 data base. Other words, combine as400 with excel data couldn't be joined by inner join codes. I need helps, whether anyone have better solutions :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using ADO, take a look at the **cwbx** objects for data transfer. Iirc, they're faster than the OLE driver, but it depends on how complex your data integration/transformation needs are.

You should find a cwbx.CHM file is in your i Series folders, but there's a good overview available from IBM on [data transfer](ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/as400/products/clientaccess/win32/presentations/spring_2007/dataxfer.pdf)